# nginx cors issue from subdomain

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

I have a nodejs api. It runs on nginx at sub.example.com.
The nginx.conf for the api looks like this:

```
server_name sub.example.com www.sub.example.com;
location / {
        if ($http_origin ~* "https?://.*\.example\.com(:[0-9]+)?") {
                set $cors "true";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                set $cors "${cors}options";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                set $cors "${cors}get";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                set $cors "${cors}post";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
                set $cors "${cors}delete";
        }
        if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
                set $cors "${cors}put";
        }
        if ($cors = "trueget") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
        if ($cors = "truepost") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
        if ($cors = "truedelete") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
        if ($cors = "trueput") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        }
        if ($cors = "trueoptions") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                return 204;
        }
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
}
```

If I make a fetch request from example.com, it works depending on how the calling client's current url looks like.

Here are the response headers for the succeeding and failing one:

```
https://example.com Works

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

https://www.example.com Doesn't work

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
```

Is the first if statement wrong for some reason? Not taking account of subdomains?
Im also a little bit scared about the response header I get when it works, stating that access control is for * (does it mean for everyone)?

Making the same call from sub2.example.com to the api at sub.example.com gives the same error as for the www. But I guess it is the same issue.

In the node app for the api I also have:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

But I dont know if this makes any difference at all.

Please note that the preflight works when calling the api from www (or also with sub2).

Comment: Configuring CORS both in NGINX and in your Node.js app is a mistake. Configure it in at most one place, wherever it's easier and where configuration changes are most likely to get reviewed.

Comment: Browsers do not like duplicate HTTP headers - in such cases all the duplicated headers will be simply ignored, as if there have never been such HTTP headers in the response.